# Is there a way not to call SaveChanges so often in the case of a junction table for a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I need to have an extra field in the junction table of a many-to-many relationship, like so:

```
public class PersonCompany
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
}
```

with these 2 classes at the ends of the relationship:

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PersonCompany> PersonCompanies { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        PersonCompanies = new List<PersonCompany>();
    }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PersonCompany> PersonCompanies { get; set; }
}
```

Yet when using it, I have to call SaveChanges on the context too many times for the primary and foreign keys to get their values, like in this example:

```
private static void AddPersonWithCompanies()
    {
        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            var person = new Person
            {
                LastName = "Dent",
                FirstName = "Juan",
                IsActive = false
            };
            context.People.Add(person);

            context.SaveChanges();

            var comp1 = new Company() { Name = "Universal" };
            var comp2 = new Company() { Name = "Lehmann" };

            context.Companies.Add(comp1);
            context.Companies.Add(comp2);

            context.SaveChanges();

            var pc1 = new PersonCompany() { Company = comp1, Person  = person, HireDate = DateTime.Today };
            var pc2 = new PersonCompany() { Company = comp2, Person=person, HireDate = DateTime.Today };

            person.PersonCompanies.Add(pc1);
            person.PersonCompanies.Add(pc2);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I would like to have only one SaveChanges() at the end but can't seem to get it...
I get the following exception if these intermediate SaveChanges() are removed:

> 

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException
  HResult=0x80131501
  Message=Unable to determine the principal end of the 'Chapter3.CSharp.Company_PersonCompanies' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at Chapter3.CSharp.Program.AddPersonWithCompanies() in C:\Users\Juan Dent\OneDrive\CSharp\Code First-Code Bundle\B03947_03_Code\Chapter3.CSharp\Program.cs:line 47
   at Chapter3.CSharp.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Juan Dent\OneDrive\CSharp\Code First-Code Bundle\B03947_03_Code\Chapter3.CSharp\Program.cs:line 14
```

Any ideas?

Regards,
Juan

Comment: This happens because the PersonCompany has composite primary key and EF will need both the entities participating in the Primary Key to be actually generated.

What you can do is remove the top-most `context.SaveChanges()`, but you still end up with two. If you want a single one, the junction table should depend only on it's own primary key.

Comment: I modified the junction table to have it's own primary key, an identity column, but have to leave the foreign keys there. The problem is still present so I don't know what good adding a separate primary key did to solve the problem. Any ideas Vect0rZ?